Xbox 360 controller support on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a late 2013, 13-inch Macbook Pro, and I'm looking into gaming on it (mainly emulation.)
Does anyone know how to get drivers for the Xbox 360 controllers set up? Thanks. :)

The first step is to watch the terminal command sudo journalctl  --follow as you connect the controller.

I've got an XBox One wireless, Afterglow Xbox 360, Sony DualSense, Zelda-
Themed switch gamepad, etc.
I've never had to set anything up. They all just work.
Kubuntu (Plasma desktop) has a gamepad section in its settings, but I don't think Ubuntu (GNOME desktop) does. But you can use Steam either way to check.
What's not working for you, specifically? When you load up Steam and look at the controller settings, does it show up?

